# USA DHS / CBP Freedom of Information Request

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I found this website where the US CBP allows me to file an FOIA request seeking information on my CBP entry / exit history and other data online.

https://foiaonline.regulations.gov/foia/action/public/request;jsessionid=0CE8C9DB2F5B0B4C73CF2C24C1614A09/createRequest

Out of curiosity I was thinking of filing a request but just curious whether this act will raise any flags that will make my travel difficult?

Let sleeping dogs lie? Any thoughts / stories?

Comment: Are you aware the [CBP I-94 website](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home) has a quick online function to show your arrival/departure history?  There is a section on the first page titled "Need A History Of Your Arrivals & Departures?" with a link to request it.  Just need to enter your name and passport details and it will give you the entry/departure info for the past 5 years.

Comment: Ah all my entries are outside of that five year window.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when filing an immigration petition, your previous immigration record is reviewable and hence the prevailing wisdom is minimize contact with immigration and not file a petition unless necessary or you're absolutely certain your record is spotless. However FOIA is not an immigration petition in itself so it would appear unlikely however nobody can tell you definitively yes or no it will lead to a review.

According to a [panel of attorneys](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/will-a-uscis-foia-request-cause-me-immigration-pro-1933186.html) you have nothing to worry about in that regard.

> **Will a USCIS FOIA request cause me immigration problems?**
>
> While generally a FOIA request should not cause you problems your
>   request will become part of your file and may constitute an admission.
>   **I typically prefer to send a simple request** rather than fill out the
>   G-639 because that form discloses a lot of unnecessary information. If
>   there is something in your past that troubles you you may consider
>   getting a PO Box address or having an attorney send the FOIA on your
>   behalf to create a layer of insulation.

It does appear you are looking at filing a simple request instead of G-639 so you should be good.